# Узнать количество букв в строке (без пробелов). без использования join

Tags: javascript, строки, length

Запросить у пользователя произвольную строку - (например: "How much is the fish?").
Запросить у пользователя ID в виде целого числа - (явно привести к числу).
ID соответствует одной из следующих операций (happy pass: считаем что пользователь всегда вводит правильные данные).
Узнать количество букв в строке (без пробелов). без использования join

```js
// randomString = randomString.split(' ');
// randomString = randomString.join('');
// randomString = randomString.length;
// console.log(randomString);
let len = randomString.split(' ').join('').length;
    
console.log(len);
```

Такие варианты пробовал, но требование без использования  join('') .
Что-то пока не могу найти дельного совета или примера .

Comment: Количество букв или символов? Без пробелов или без пробельных символов?

Comment: Точки, запятые, ?, ! и прочие знаки считать за буквы или нет?

Comment: Скорей просто букв исключить , только пробелы . Наверное другие символы (! , ? ) можно счтитать  .

Comment: "happy pass" -> "happy path"

Comment: тз не я писал ) Чисто копипаст ) Это вопрос к преподу )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не учитывать только пробелы, так заменить их на пустоту

```js
let rand_str = "how much is the fish"
rand_str = rand_str.replace(/\s/g, '');
console.log(rand_str.length)
```

Ну, либо через `match` метод

```js
let rand_str = "How much is the fish"
let len = rand_str.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g).length
console.log(len)
```

Во втором случае считаем только количество букв встречающихся в строке и только латинского алфавита.

Можно еще кириллицу добавить

```js
let rand_str = "How much is the fish НУ сколько же"
let len = rand_str.match(/[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]/g).length
console.log(len)
```

И так далее...

Answer (score 1):

```js
const randomString = "How much is the fish?";
const len = randomString.split('').filter(c => c != ' ').length;
console.log(len);
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно, поиздеваться над строкой

```js
let len = "How much is the fish?".split("").reduce((acc, char) =>
// Ваши символы которые не должны учавствовать в подсчете
" ?!".includes(char)? acc: ++acc, 0);
    
console.log(len);
```